# White/blank screen when loading OpenERP

Tags: javascript, python, postgresql, odoo, openerp-7

I am trying to open OpenERP using url `http:// ip:port/` but it shows blank/white screen instead of login form. Earlier in the morning it was working fine.
I don't remember any particular changes that i have done on server except i was trying to remove pagination using limit in setting->action-> window and updating following method at

```
\openerp\addons\web\static\src\js
```

`File view_list.js` Line num 117

```
limit: function () {
    if (this._limit === undefined) {
        this._limit = (this.options.limit
                    || this.defaults.limit
                    || (this.getParent().action || {}).limit
                    || 80);
    }
    return this._limit;
},
```

I have reverted changes in code.

I tried restarting Postgresql, OpenERP server, restarting my router etc, but issue is same. I am running out of ideas. Kindly Help!

Regards....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check that server is running or not.
Restart the server in eclipse or run the server in terminal using this comment

```
/openerp-server -c /etc/openerp-server.conf -d db_name --worker=0
```

Open the openerp-server file location in terminal, which will be in folder where you installed the Openerp. Then run this comment. Give your data base name in "db_name". Then try it. Or else one again check your "ip:port".